# Swagger.io incorrectly generates "in" and "body" tags in json file

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have this code...

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/search/",
      method = RequestMethod.GET,
      produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ApiOperation(value = "Search for a Device",
      response = DeviceSummary.class,
      position = 0)
  List<DeviceSummary> search(@ApiParam(value = "The store code", required = true) @QueryParam("storeCode") String storeCode,
                             @ApiParam(value = "The device type code", required = false) @QueryParam("deviceType") String deviceType,
                             @ApiParam(value = "The device type codes", required = false) @QueryParam("deviceTypes") String deviceTypes,
                             @ApiParam(value = "The device group code", required = false) @QueryParam("deviceGroupCode") String deviceGroupCode,
                             @ApiParam(value = "Max results to return", required = false) @QueryParam("maxResults") String maxResults);
```

And the swagger.json file looks like this..

```
"parameters" : [ {
          "in" : "body",
          "name" : "body",
          "description" : "The store code",
          "required" : true,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }, {
          "in" : "body",
          "name" : "body",
          "description" : "The device type code",
          "required" : false,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }, <SNIP>
```

I was expecting the Query Params to look like this...
Notice the "in" type is "query", not "body". Also, the name is correct.

```
{
    "name" : "storeCode",
    "in" : "query",
    "description" : "The store code",
    "required" : true,
    "type" : "string"
}
```

I'm using these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to NOT mix JaxRS and Spring annotations.

It should be...@RequestParam, not @QueryParam

```
@ApiParam(value = "The store code", required = true) @RequestParam("storeCode") String storeCode,
```